# Rhino Service Bus - Load Balance \ Distributor capabilities

Tags: servicebus, rhino-servicebus

I'm looking into Rhino Service Bus for a project instead of using commercial NServiceBus (which I know from my workplace).

In NServiceBus there's the concept of a distributor, which load balances tasks between server automatically to allow scale up. I searched and found a similar question about RSB, but with no example on how to actually implement it. RSB is a bit short in documentation (they have example projects on GitHub, but non with such example).

Does anyone know how to implement load balancing in RSB? or have any link to an article about it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are in the evaluation phase you are welcome to have a look at my FOSS service bus: https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-esb

Comment: @EbenRoux is there a list of supported features? does it support hosting in asp.net environment? thanks

Comment: well, not really a list of features (not a bad idea), but yes it can be hosted in asp.net.

Comment: @EbenRoux Thanks. Will have a look :)